# What are the steps in converting a Desktop application in libgdx to android?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a fully functioning java application built with the libgdx framework that deploys on the desktop. However, I would like to take the code and create and Android app from it.

I have created the Android Project, rerouted code to the source folder of the Android Project, added an Android Specific Main Method, and edited manifest xml file to use the main activity - in this case "RoadRusherActivity". However, I run into the following error:

```
04-28 15:44:41.195: E/Trace(2452): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-28 15:44:41.355: D/dalvikvm(2452): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.me.mygdxgame-2/libgdx.so 0x40ce58c8
04-28 15:44:41.385: D/dalvikvm(2452): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.me.mygdxgame-2/libgdx.so 0x40ce58c8
04-28 15:44:41.415: D/dalvikvm(2452): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.me.mygdxgame-2/libgdx.so 0x40ce58c8, skipping init
04-28 15:44:41.465: D/libEGL(2452): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
04-28 15:44:41.485: D/libEGL(2452): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
04-28 15:44:41.675: D/AndroidRuntime(2452): Shutting down VM
04-28 15:44:41.675: W/dalvikvm(2452): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.me.mygdxgame/com.me.mygdxgame.RoadRusherActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10048 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10048 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.acquireWakeLock(IPowerManager.java:271)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquireLocked(PowerManager.java:717)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire(PowerManager.java:686)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.onResume(AndroidApplication.java:241)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5182)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
04-28 15:44:41.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2452):     ... 12 more
04-28 15:44:47.705: I/Process(2452): Sending signal. PID: 2452 SIG: 9
```

The following is my manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.me.mygdxgame"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".RoadRusherActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The following is my main activity class titled "RoadRusherActivity".

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
public class RoadRusherActivity extends AndroidApplication {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    config.useAccelerometer = false;
    config.useCompass = false;
    config.useWakelock = true;
    config.useGL20 = true;
    initialize(new SimpleBike(), config);
}
}
```

I am just confused as how to approach, porting to Android. Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a `libs/` directory with the required jars? (see: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup)

Comment: There was an issue with jars in the libs directory. I fixed that issue, and now I am receiving a different error message which I have posted above.

Comment: Thanks damo - you were completely right!

Comment: No problem, see the updated answer regarding keeping the screen on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The updated exception identifies the issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10048 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
```

You just need to add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

see: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationConfiguration#Permissions

Alternatively, if you didn't intend to use wake locking, remove the line `config.useWakelock = true;` from `RoadRusherActivity`

**Update:** As mentioned in the comments below, if you are just looking to keep the screen on you should use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` instead of wake locks. Add this to your `onCreate` method:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: A game that is using wake locks to keep the screen on during gameplay is doing it wrong. You should use the KEEP_SCREEN_ON  flag/setKeepScreenOn(true) view method instead. This is less error-prone than wake locks and does not require a permission.

Comment: Could you please just get rid of the part about adding the permission?  You don't need to do that if you are using the window flag.  There are way too many games on the play store that request this permission. :(

Comment: I'm leaving the part about the wake lock permissions because it solves the original issue (which might help someone else in the future who legitimately needs to use wake locks).